# Activity With buttons show blank

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

**Notice I edited the XML File!!!!**

I got an Activity that create a button and when you click on the button it calls to another Activity but when i run the app it's shows just a blank page.
Activity:

```
package com.elichai.tfillin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
private void displayCamera() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    //Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayCamera();
            //finish();
        }
      });
}
}
```

And here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="223dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
        android:text="@string/switch_cam"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: plz show CameraActivity Activity code and layout or make sure you have added setContentView in onCreate of CameraActivity Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K It dosen't matter because it's don't even show the buttons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the layout. In your MainActivity class, the onCreate() method signature is written incorrectly. Use onCreate() instead of OnCreate(). (small 'o')
The system calls onCreate() when creating your activity.

Comment: Thanks!(First after i changed the onCreate it didn't help me but then i switched back to FrameLayout and it's solved)

Answer (score 0):

Try using A **RelativeLayout** in place of **FrameLayout** unless there was relay a need of using it.

or if you want to use FrameLayout try this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="223dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
        android:text="switchcam"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**layout_** margins does not work in ***FrameLayout*** until you also set your subviews layout gravity e.g.

```
android:layout_gravity="top"
```

( for **framelayout**)

Comment: did you try using the above xml complete?

Comment: yes.but that wasn't the problem the problem was the onCreate Capital O. but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **FrameLayout** with a vertical **LinearLayout**